# Minikube Dashboard: Can I use a specific version of the kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Minikube 1.5.2 comes with the new Kubernetes Dashboard which is beta and I have quite some trouble with it. So I would like to use the latest stable release. I tried to apply the deployment.yml of the dashboard project, but that does not help (I changed the namespaces to fit the minikube standard configuration). I guess thats due to the addon mechanism of minikube.

Any ideas how I get the stable 1.10.1 running in minikube (https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases)?

Comment: Minikube 1.5.2 runs on kubernetes 1.16.2. As per dashboard changelog version 1.10.1 is not compatible with this k8s version. See here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases/tag/v1.10.1 . What kind of issues are facing with thew new dashboard? I launched it and it was working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you I missed the incompability. The dasboard is crashing, config map entries disapear, updated values are not persisted... So I'll rely on kubectl.